# Notepad ++ folding, using same character as open and close?

Tags: notepad++, folding

I work with a program that uses .txt files to control system options and I am trying to use Notepad ++ to make these files a bit easier to read.

As an example, I will have following in file Settings.txt

```
[Section1]
Setting1=Y
Setting2=N
Setting3=OptionY

[Section2]
MoreSettings1=Today
ExtraSQL= (Select * from Table Where.....)
Setting4=Y

[Section3]
EvenMoreSettings=X
```

I have been able to create a User Defined Language and make the section headers bold, and colour anything after an = to make it a bit clearer to read which is a good start.

But I now want to be able to collapse the sections that I dont want to see, e.g

```
+[Section1]
+[Section2]
+[Section3]
```

However, I'm struggling to understand the options in the Folder & Default Tab and cannot make it work?

I think I want the open and close tag to be [, but that obviously doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options seem to produce the desired effect:

Folding in code 1 style (bottom left panel):

```
Open: ]

Middle: (blank)

Close: [
```

Comment: Thanks Davesoft, when I first tried your suggestion it did not work. It seems that because I already had the [ and ] characters as line styles elsewhere, it was not working. Removing the other line styles made the fold work. Thanks!